# How to add cocoa pods to existing project?

Tags: ios

I am following this tutorial for cocoapods.

What is the best way to add pods to an existing project?

`pod init` and copy and pasting the swift files from an existing cocoapod enabled project, or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't add the swift files, you just specify the pods in the pod file and then install them with `pod istall`. Read up on it here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods

Comment: what if you need the exact same swift file; i suppose one could just create a new swift file and copy and paste. The real problem is i need the same storyboard?